# How to align multiline selection in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I use HTML5 in windows 10 to write a website.
I want to align from
[image]

to style like this:
[image]

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
<form>
         </select><br>
      <label for="name_1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Discipline Code(e.g. ACC): &nbsp;</label>          <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1"><br>
      <label for="name_2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Course Code(e.g. 201): &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>          <input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2"><br>
      <label for="name_3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Course Title: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>          <input type="text" id="name_3" name="name_3" ><br>

       <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Postgraduate Course: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <select id="postgraduate-course" >
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Dropdown_yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="Dropdown_no">No</option>
            </select><br>
                   <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;First Presenting Semester: </label>
            <select id="presenting-semester" >
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Dropdown_Jan">January</option>
                <option value="Dropdown_Jul">July</option>
            </select><br>
                               <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Year: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <select id="year" >
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Dropdown_2021">2021</option>
                <option value="Dropdown_2022">2022</option>
            </select><br>
                  ......            
        <br>
         </form>
         {% endblock %}
```

That is , I want to make the beginning of all text-input and selection aligned.
The label could keep it's current position.

Comment: Small accessibility enhancement: If you add an attribute `for="id-of-the-input"` to your `<label>`s, they become clickable and will focus the input element, if clicked. E.g., `<label for="year">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a good project!

For fine-tuned styling you need to get rid of *all* the `&nbsp;`s. Then add an element `<style></style>` somewhere in your HTML file. (Usually styles go inside `<head>`, but another position will do as well.)

Inside the `style` element you can use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS) to address your HTML elements.

Try starting with the following lines:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This will advise the browser to make all `<label>` elements 200px wide and align the text to the right, with 10px space to the following elements.

Answer (score 1):

As you will see using `&nbsp;` is bad practice and not necessary. You should instead use [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) and [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding). But the following example might be enough to help you get started in the right direction.

```css
label {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label for="name_1">Discipline Code(e.g. ACC): </label>
<input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1"><br>
<label for="name_2">Course Code(e.g. 201): </label>
<input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2"><br>
<label for="name_3">Course Title: </label>
<input type="text" id="name_3" name="name_3" ><br>

<label>Postgraduate Course: </label>
<select id="postgraduate-course" >
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Dropdown_yes">Yes</option>
<option value="Dropdown_no">No</option>
</select><br>
<label>First Presenting Semester: </label>
<select id="presenting-semester" >
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Dropdown_Jan">January</option>
<option value="Dropdown_Jul">July</option>
</select><br>
<label>Year: </label>
<select id="year" >
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Dropdown_2021">2021</option>
<option value="Dropdown_2022">2022</option>
</select><br>
```

Also note instead of using `<br>` for a new line consider using a `<div>` instead something like

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="name_1">Discipline Code(e.g. ACC): </label>
  <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="name_2">Course Code(e.g. 201): </label>
  <input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="name_3">Course Title: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name_3" name="name_3" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS Flexbox Modal` or `CSS Grid Layout` to achieve this type of grid.

```css
.form-row {
    display:  flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.form-col {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrap">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-col">
            <label for="name_1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Discipline Code(e.g. ACC)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-col">
            <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-col">
            <label for="name_2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Course Code(e.g. 201)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-col">
            <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap each pair of label + input/select element into a `div` element which will serve as a form row, and you can set a custom class (e.g form-row) name to that `div` element like the following:

```
  .form-row { 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0; 
  }
  .form-row label {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .form-row select,
  .form-row input {
    float: left;
  }
```